# Print SVG charts into PPML format

Tags: php, xml, printing, svg, yui

Our printer is set up to handle PPML files.

We would like to include some SVG charts to be printed. SVG Charts are built with PHP and YUI3.

How to incorporate SVG charts into PPML files?
How to include YUI3 charts into PPML?

Answer (score 1):

In your PPML file, I believe you should be able to add the tag below:

```
<SOURCE Dimensions="thewidthinpixels theheightinpixels" Format="image/svg+xml">
<EXTERNAL_DATA Src="yoursvgfilepath.svg" />
</SOURCE>
```

Here's an example PPML file (although it doesn't include an SVG example):
[Example PPML code](http://nkrijger.blogspot.com/2008/10/ppml-example.html)

And, if you wanted to just copy and paste the svg in, it appears you can embed it as internal data, too:
[W3C reference regarding use of SVG in PPML](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGPrintPrimer12/#ppml)